# Singleton Inheritance Buggy Behavior

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, extends, es6-class

I have spotted buggy behavior in javascript es6 inheritance using Singleton pattern.

**Code is**:

```
let instanceOne = null;

class One {
    constructor() {
        if (instanceOne) return instanceOne;

        this.name = 'one';
        instanceOne = this;
        return instanceOne;
    }

    method() {
        console.log('Method in one');
    }
}


let instanceTwo = null;

class Two extends One {
    constructor() {
        super();

        if (instanceTwo) return instanceTwo;

        this.name = 'two';
        instanceTwo = this;
        return instanceTwo;
    }

    method() {
        console.log('Method in two');
    }
}

const objOne = new One();
const objTwo = new Two();

console.log(objOne.name);
console.log(objTwo.name);
objOne.method();
objTwo.method();
```

**Display is**:

```
two
two
Method in one
Method in one
```

The inheritance get fucked up somehow. Here the attributes get overridden but not the object methods.

My question is why is it working (like now throw) and can you explain this behavior?

It appears that new objects need brand new object as parent (see solution below).

---

If you encounter the same problem, here is my solution:

```
let instanceOne = null;

class One {
    constructor(brandNewInstance = false) {
        if (instanceOne && !brandNewInstance) return instanceOne;

        this.name = 'one';

        if (brandNewInstance) return this;

        instanceOne = this;
        return instanceOne;
    }

    method() {
        console.log('Method in one');
    }
}


let instanceTwo = null;

class Two extends One {
    constructor() {
        super(true);

        if (instanceTwo) return instanceTwo;

        this.name = 'two';
        instanceTwo = this;
        return instanceTwo;
    }

    method() {
        console.log('Method in two');
    }
}
```

---

I use node.js v6.9.1

Comment: Well, don't use singletons. `instanceOne === instanceTwo` is exactly what you'll get when you want only a single instance. Don't use inheritance for singletons objects.

Comment: I think there is no theorical explaination about why inherit a singleton class is bad (To me Singleton pattern means you want to give access to functionnalities from only one canal). We shouldn't restaint ourselves because it result to a technical error.

Comment: There is no technical error here, at most a programming mistake. The theoretical explanation is that singleton patterns are bad in general (they are global state), and your idea that a singleton would be implemented using a class is misguided (probably from languages that don't know anything else than classes). Just use a simple object (literal). You can even inherit from that in JS if you care to.

Comment: Ok for the misguidance. I disagree about that the singleton are bad, for example you want to Log something, you don't need multiple instance of same class to attend the job. Thanks you for your time

Comment: Well, then instantiate it only once (or make it one static object). But there's no point in putting that restriction onto the class itself. Btw, if you want only a single channel for your logs, how would that work with two instances (`instanceOne` and `instanceTwo`)?

Comment: Well the Log was an exemple. It's way more complex in my real context. I agree with your point for the instantiation. I use this code to get the class object tho `static getInstance() {return instance || new One(); }`. The point to get the check inside the constructor too is to avoid trouble if some other developper use my class using `new` instead of `getInstance()`. (You are sure there will never be a second instance, wathever the way the other developper use it)

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT I've updated the answer to target the problem more precisely. In the case you've described it is common to make constructor throw with `shouldn't be called directly` when it is instantiated with `new`.

Comment: Yes, `static getInstance()` (which stores a singleton instance per (sub)class) would be solution. But really, if you don't want anyone to instantiate objects by using the constructor, don't use `class`es.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing something a bit strange. Constructors and subclasses in ecmascript 6 do not work in the way you think they do. You may wish to read [this blog post](http://www.2ality.com/2015/02/es6-classes-final.html) (particularly section 4) to learn more.

Taking from that article, your code looks like this under the hood:

```
let instanceOne = null;

function One() {
//  var this = Object.create(new.target.prototype);  // under the hood

    if (instanceOne) return instanceOne;

    this.name = 'one';
    instanceOne = this;
    return instanceOne;
}
One.prototype.method = function() { console.log('Method in one'); }

let instanceTwo = null;

function Two() {
    var that = undefined;

    that = Reflect.construct(One, [], new.target);

    if (instanceTwo) return instanceTwo;

    that.name = 'two';
    instanceTwo = that;
    return instanceTwo;
}
Two.prototype.method = function() { console.log('Method in two'); }
Object.setPrototypeOf(Two, One);
Object.setPrototypeOf(Two.prototype, One.prototype);

const objOne = Reflect.construct(One, [], One);
const objTwo = Reflect.construct(Two, [], Two);

console.log(objOne.name);
console.log(objTwo.name);
objOne.method();
objTwo.method();
```

(new.target is the value passed as the third argument of `Reflect.construct`)

You can see that for the `Two` class, no new object is being created and `Two.prototype` is not used. Instead, the `One` singleton instance is used and mutated.

Comment: So, are you saying that `Two.prototype` is not used because of the explicit return? I mean, wouldn't there normally be a step in the `Two` constructor to add `Two.prototype` on to `that` and then do another `Object.create(that)`, on the augmented `that`, to construct the extended prototype chain? Because, according to the blog you referenced, you normally can supersede static methods when extending...

Comment: @CoolBlue In ecmascript 6 the prototype chain is made backwards, sort of. The `Two` constructor passes a reference to the `Two` object to the `One` constructor. `One` constructor makes a new object whose prototype is `new.target.prototype`... which is `Two`. The prototype of `Two` is `One`, so the resultant object has the correct prototype chain. It's just that in the question, this object with the correct prototype chain is discarded, instead the `instanceOne` singleton is returned.

Comment: Thanks @Oliver, but I'm still confused. _**1.**_ Your statement: "new.target is the value passed as the first argument of Reflect.construct" appears to be the opposite of the actual case. _**2**_. You seem to be mixing code and pseudocode in the `One` constructor by using `that` when `this` is already doing the same thing under the hood. For me, this is confusing. _**3.**_ Shouldn't `Object.setPrototypeOf(Two, One)` be `Object.setPrototypeOf(Two.prototype, One.prototype)` for proper inheritance?

Comment: @CoolBlue I suggest reading the linked article! (section 4). My answer just paraphrases it. 1) you're right, it should be 'third argument'. 2) it's not pseudocode as it executes correctly. I was trying to demonstrate what the underlying javascript engine was doing, and `this` is not assignable to. The point was to show what is going on under the hood. 3) No, because Two is a subclass of One: The prototype of a subclass is the superclass in ECMAScript 6. Again, read the linked article as it explains much better than I can. There are diagrams!

Comment: I followed your suggestion and re-read the linked blog. Thanks to your explanation and the poking around in devtools that I did, my understanding is much better now. If you check out section 4.1 you will see that we are both right: in fact you need to _add_ the line I suggested in point 3 above. As you said, the [[Prototype]] of a subclass is the superclass but, also, the [[Prototype]] of the `prototype` of the subclass is the `prototype` of the superclass. For point 2, I suggested an edit to your question that, to me anyway, is easier to understand. Please feel free to roll it back!

Comment: @CoolBlue Surely the line `Object.setPrototypeOf(Two.prototype, One.prototype);` is redundant, given that `Two.prototype == One`, and therefore `Object.setPrototypeOf(Two.prototype, One.prototype)` is equivalent to `Object.SetPrototypeOf(One, One.prototype)` and thus makes no change?

Comment: Actually, `Two.prototype != One`, `Two.__proto__ === One` and `Two.prototype.__proto__ === One.prototype`. So it's not redundant. Check it out in devtools. You need to include both `setPrototypeOf` lines to get the exact same structure as a Class. It's not just copying prototype, it's establishing the [[Prototype]] relationship.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because of this line:

```
    if (instanceOne) return instanceOne;
```

`One` constructor runs twice in the code above. Second `One` call is `super()`, in this case `this` is created from `Two.prototype`, and object method is `Two.prototype.method`.

Return statement from `super()` substitutes `this` with `One` singleton, and then `Two` constructor just modifies `One` singleton instance.

Static property can be used instead to hold instances:

```
constructor() {
    if (this.constructor.hasOwnProperty('instance'))
        return this.constructor.instance;

    this.constructor.instance = this;

    this.name = 'one';
}
```

Or if sharing an instance with descendant classes is the expected behaviour,

```
constructor() {
    if ('instance' in this.constructor)
        return this.constructor.instance;

    this.name = 'one';
    this.constructor.instance = this;
}
```

In this case all singleton mechanics is done by `One` constructor, `Two` just needs to call `super`:

```
constructor() {
    super();

    this.name = 'two';
}
```

Also, ending `return` statement is redundant. `this` doesn't have to be returned explicitly.